# Optimizing Python script with multiple for loops

Tags: python, performance, list, optimization

I'm super new at python and super new at trying to optimize a script for speed.  I've got this problem that I've been using to teach myself how to write code and here it is:

I have a dataset with a list of products, their value and their costs. There are three different types of products (A,B,C) - there are anywhere from 30-100 products for each product type.  Each product has a value and a cost.  I have to select 1 product from product type A, 2 from product type B, and 3 from products type C -- once I use a product, I cannot use it again (no replacement).

My goal is to optimize the value of products given my budget constraint.

Given that I'm basically trying to create a list of combinations, I started there and wrote a few "for loops" in order to achieve that.  I initially tried to do too much in the loops and change the data type to list because from my research it sounded like that it would speed it up -- it did speed it up immensely.

The problem is that I am still processing 350k records a second at best, which puts me at about 7 hours to complete if I have 30 items in list_a, 50 in list_b, and 50 in list_c.

I have created 3 lists of lists -- (list_a, list_b, and list_c) that each look like my example below for list_a.  Then, I evaluate each permutation inside the for loop to see if this permutation has a higher value than the current highest value permutation and that the cost is below the constraint.  If it meets those conditions, I append it to the masterlist of permutations (combo_list).

```
    list_a = [['product1','product1_cost','product1_value'],['product2','product2_cost','product2_value'],...]

    num_a = len(list_a)
    num_b = len(list_b)
    num_c = len(list_c)

    combo_list = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] # this is to create the list of lists that I will populate

    a = 0 #for row numbers
    b1 = 0 
    c1 = 0 
    l = 0 #of iterations
    max_value = 0

    for a in range(0,num_a):
      for b1 in range(0,num_b):
        b2 = b1 + 1 #second b
          for b2 in range(b2,num_b):
            for c1 in range(0,num_c):
              c2 = c1 +1 #second c
                for c2 in range(c2,num_C):
                  c3 =c2+1 #third c
                  for c3 in range(c3,num_C):
                    data = [list_a[a][0],list_a[a][1],list_a[a][2],list_b[b1][0],list_b[b1][1],list_b[b1][2],list_b[b2][0],list_b[b2][1],list_b[b2][2],list_c[c1][0],list_c[c1][1],list_c[c1][2],list_c[c2][0],list_c[c2][1],list_c[c2][2],list_c[c3][0],list_c[c3][1],list_c[c3][2]]
                    total_cost = data[1] + data[4] + data[7] + data[10] + data[13] + data[16]
                    total_value = data[2] + data[5] + data[8] + data[11] + data[14] + data[17]
                    data[18]=total_cost
                    data[19]=total_value
                    if total_value >= max_value and total_cost <= constraint:
                      combo_list.append(data)
                      max_value = total_value
                    c3 +=1
                l +=1
                c2 +=1
            c1 +=1
        b2+=1
    b1 +=1
a +=1
```

then I turn it into a dataframe or csv

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If you have slow but working code that you'd like to optimize, it might be a good candidate for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: You might find your code easier to reason about it you split it down into functions, and perhaps use some of the built in tools like https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations.

Comment: Why are you looping over `range(b2,num_b)` using `b2`? As well as defining `b2 = b1 + 1 #second b`? This seems like potentially very confusing notation. More substantively, you can cut down on expressing strings and calculate `total_cost` using a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Isn't that the knapsack problem? And isn't the knapsack problem NP? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity

Comment: @Mark Tozzi -- thanks for pointing that out.  I had never heard of it, and it appears to be pretty close to it.  I'm going to read through it.  Thanks

Comment: @tomDalton - thanks for the help.   I figured out the combos pretty easily for product b and product c.  Trying to pull it all together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to figure this out using itertools combinations:

```
tup_b =  itertools.combinations(list_b, 2)
list_b = map(list,tup_b)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(list_b)

#Extending the list
df_b['B'] = df_b[0] + df_b[1] 
df_b = df_b[['B']]

#flatten list
b = df_b.values.tolist()
b = list(itertools.chain(*r))

# adding values and costs
r = len(b)
x=0
for x in range(0,r):
    cost = [b[x][1] +b[x][4]]
    value = [b[x][2] +b[x][5]]
    r[x] = r[x] +cost +value
    x +=1

#shortening list
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b)
df_b = df_b[[0,3,6,7]]
df_b.columns = ['B1','B2','cost','value']
```

Then, I did the same for list_c with similar structure as above, using this:

```
tup_c =  itertools.combinations(list_c, 3)
```

Using this dropped by time to process from ~5 hours to 8 minutes...

Thanks all for the help.